# Login with Facebook doesn't work in Facebook App but it works in browser

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, canvas, authentication

I've made a website which allow you to login with Facebook using the Javascript SDK, than I show it in a Facebook App with a Facebook Canvas.
It works fine on PC, both in website and Facebook Canvas App.
I tried it on Android Browser and it works fine, but if I post the url on Facebook, and I click it, Facebook loads it inside the Facebook Android App, and when I click on the Login Button nothing happens.
What could be wrong?

(I use JQuery)

Comment: Did the phone ask you how to open the link or juat went to the facebook app?

Comment: Seems like a bug in facebooks internal webview/browser: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/727993910619407/